# How can I save and retrieve an entire <div> using HTML5's Web Storage API

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-storage

I want to save and retrieve some content of html after adding them from javascript and not losing them after refreshing

```js
// hide/show the header
$("#icon").click(function(){
 $("#add-new-todo").fadeToggle();
});


// delete a todo onclick
$("#todo").on("click", ".delete", function(event) {
 $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
  $(this).remove();
 });

 event.stopPropagation();
});


//function that scratch the finished todo
$("#todo").on("click", ".todoList", function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});
  
// format date to: weekday - year - month - day - time
function formatDate()
{
 var event = new Date();
 var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', 
     day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'};

 return event.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
}


// clear the input field after adding a todo
function clearAll() {
 let title = document.getElementById('todoTitle');
 let content = document.getElementById('todoContent');

 title.value = "";
 content.value = "";
}


// add a new todo
function addNewToDo()
{
 let title = document.getElementById('todoTitle');
 let content = document.getElementById('todoContent');

 if ((title.value == null || title.value == "") ||
  (content.value == null || content.value == "")) {
  alert("Please fill all the required fields!");
  // clearAll();
  return false;
 }

 let parentDiv = document.getElementById('todo');

 let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
 newDiv.className = "todoList";

 let conDiv = document.createElement("div");
 conDiv.className = "content";

 let delDiv = document.createElement("div");
 delDiv.className = "delete";
 delDiv.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>";

 let header = document.createElement("h2");
 header.innerHTML = title.value;

 let dateContent = document.createElement("p");
 dateContent.className = "date";
 let date = formatDate();
 dateContent.innerHTML = "added: " + date;

 let subject = document.createElement("p");
 subject.className = "subject";
 subject.innerHTML = content.value;

 conDiv.appendChild(header);
 conDiv.appendChild(dateContent);
 conDiv.appendChild(subject);
 
 newDiv.appendChild(delDiv);
 newDiv.appendChild(conDiv);
 // newDiv.appendChild(delDiv);

 parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);

 clearAll();
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #2BC0E4;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

#container {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 150px auto;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 3%;
}

#todo {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#title {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}

#items-title {
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

form {
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
}


.form-lines:first-child input {
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.form-lines:first-child input[type="text"] {
    width: 62%;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#todoButton {
    width: 28%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #2980b9;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}

#todoButton:hover {
    background-color: #206592;
    font-size: 19px;
}

.form-lines:nth-child(2) input {
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    width: 92%;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}

.form-lines input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: 2px solid #2980b9;
    background-color: #fff;
}


#icon {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px; 
}

hr {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto 5px;
}

.todoList {
    width: 93%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5%;
    margin: auto auto 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.delete {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 40px 10px 0px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

.content h2 {
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.content .date {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    margin: 0;
    width: 77%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.conten .subject {
    margin: 15px auto;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.completed {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

     <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
       <div id="title">
        <div>
                        <h1>
                            SEF Todo List<span id="icon"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
                        </h1> 
           
                    </div>
       </div>

       <div id="add-new-todo">
        <div id="items-title">
         <h1>Item</h1> 
        </div>

     <form>
      <div class="form-lines">     
       <input type="text" name="todoTitle" placeholder="Enter title" id="todoTitle">
       <input type="button" name="todoButton" value="Add" id="todoButton" onclick="addNewToDo()">
      </div>

      <div class="form-lines">
       <input type="text" name="todoContent" placeholder="Enter what To Do" id="todoContent">
      </div>

     </form> 
       </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div id="todo"></div>
     </div>




        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my code with all the files, the project is about building a small todo webapp that should use the storage of the browser
I was trying to use localStorage but it saves the div as an object without the content

The new divs are inserted in the  using javascript addNewToDo()
I want store all the appended divs in that div to retrieve them upon reloading of the page

thanks in advance

UPDATE:
after asking the instructor for more details, he said that we should not store the whole div tag, what we are interested in is the content it contains

So here's my solution, feel free to give your feedback I would appreciate it

```js
// initialize the itemsArray to [] or to the existing previous todos
let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));


// hide/show the header
$("#icon").click(function(){
 $("#add-new-todo").fadeToggle();
});


// delete a todo onclick
$("#todo").on("click", ".delete", function(event) {
 $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
  let idxDel = $(this).index();
  
  // call the function that deletes the div from the localStorage
  deleteFromStorage(idxDel);
  $(this).remove();
 });
 event.stopPropagation();
});


//function that scratch the finished todo
$("#todo").on("click", ".todoList", function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});
  

// format date to: weekday - year - month - day - time
function formatDate()
{
 var event = new Date();
 var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', 
     day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: false};

 return event.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
}


// clear the input field after adding a todo
function clearAll() {
 let title = document.getElementById('todoTitle');
 let content = document.getElementById('todoContent');

 title.value = "";
 content.value = "";
}


// add a new todo
function addNewToDo()
{
 let title = document.getElementById('todoTitle');
 let content = document.getElementById('todoContent');

 if ((title.value == null || title.value == "") ||
  (content.value == null || content.value == "")) {
  alert("Please fill all the required fields!");
  return false;
 }

 let parentDiv = document.getElementById('todo');

 let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
 newDiv.className = "todoList";

 let conDiv = document.createElement("div");
 conDiv.className = "content";

 let delDiv = document.createElement("div");
 delDiv.className = "delete";
 delDiv.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>";

 let header = document.createElement("h2");
 header.innerHTML = title.value;

 let dateContent = document.createElement("p");
 dateContent.className = "date";
 let date = formatDate();
 dateContent.innerHTML = "added: " + date;

 let subject = document.createElement("p");
 subject.className = "subject";
 subject.innerHTML = content.value;

 conDiv.appendChild(header);
 conDiv.appendChild(dateContent);
 conDiv.appendChild(subject);
 
 newDiv.appendChild(delDiv);
 newDiv.appendChild(conDiv);

 addToLocalStorage(title.value, "added: " + date, content.value);

 parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);

 clearAll();
}


// save the added todo to the localStorage
function addToLocalStorage (title, date, subject)
{
 obj = {"title" : String(title),
     "date": String(date),
     "subject": String(subject)};
 itemsArray.push(obj);

 // add the new item added to data array to be available for other functions
 data = itemsArray;
 localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
} 


// retrieve all the todos from the localStorage
function retrieveToDo()
{
 let parentDiv = document.getElementById('todo');
 
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.className = "todoList";

  let conDiv = document.createElement("div");
  conDiv.className = "content";

  let delDiv = document.createElement("div");
  delDiv.className = "delete";
  delDiv.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>";

  let header = document.createElement("h2");
  header.innerHTML = data[i].title;

  let dateContent = document.createElement("p");
  dateContent.className = "date";
  dateContent.innerHTML = data[i].date;

  let subject = document.createElement("p");
  subject.className = "subject";
  subject.innerHTML = data[i].subject;

  conDiv.appendChild(header);
  conDiv.appendChild(dateContent);
  conDiv.appendChild(subject);
  
  newDiv.appendChild(delDiv);
  newDiv.appendChild(conDiv);

  parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
 }
}


// delete a specific todo from the localStorage
function deleteFromStorage(idxDel)
{
 data.splice(idxDel, 1);;
 localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: Save the `div`'s `outerHTML`.

Comment: But it would be better saving only the data entered using JSON stringify, and re-creating the `div`s on load using JS.

Comment: Don't save it as HTML, this could lead to security issues. What if I would save this HTML `<script>some malicious script</script>`. Build the HTML on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better save json to map;But if you want use html,you can save todoList after append newDIV,like this:

```
        parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
        storage.setItem('originList', parentDiv.innerHTML);
```

and in the page ,you should init addNewToDo function. like this:

```
         if (type) {
            var originListHtml = storage.getItem('originList');
            if (!parentDiv.innerHTML) {
                parentDiv.innerHTML = originListHtml;
            }
            return;
        }
```

above can ok; Please see the following example，Hope can help you ：）

```js
// hide/show the header
$("#icon").click(function() {
  $("#add-new-todo").fadeToggle();
});


// delete a todo onclick
$("#todo").on("click", ".delete", function(event) {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });

  event.stopPropagation();
});


//function that scratch the finished todo
$("#todo").on("click", ".todoList", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

// format date to: weekday - year - month - day - time
function formatDate() {
  var event = new Date();
  var options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric'
  };

  return event.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
}


// clear the input field after adding a todo
function clearAll() {
  let title = document.getElementById('todoTitle');
  let content = document.getElementById('todoContent');

  title.value = "";
  content.value = "";
}


// add a new todo
function addNewToDo(type) {
  let title = document.getElementById('todoTitle');
  let content = document.getElementById('todoContent');

  // 判断初始化的时候显示之前localStorage的内容
  if (type) {
    var originListHtml = storage.getItem('originList');
    if (!parentDiv.innerHTML) {
      parentDiv.innerHTML = originListHtml;
    }
    return;
  }
  if ((title.value == null || title.value == "") ||
    (content.value == null || content.value == "")) {
    alert("Please fill all the required fields!");
    // clearAll();
    return false;
  }

  let parentDiv = document.getElementById('todo');

  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.className = "todoList";

  let conDiv = document.createElement("div");
  conDiv.className = "content";

  let delDiv = document.createElement("div");
  delDiv.className = "delete";
  delDiv.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>";

  let header = document.createElement("h2");
  header.innerHTML = title.value;

  let dateContent = document.createElement("p");
  dateContent.className = "date";
  let date = formatDate();
  dateContent.innerHTML = "added: " + date;

  let subject = document.createElement("p");
  subject.className = "subject";
  subject.innerHTML = content.value;

  conDiv.appendChild(header);
  conDiv.appendChild(dateContent);
  conDiv.appendChild(subject);

  newDiv.appendChild(delDiv);
  newDiv.appendChild(conDiv);
  // newDiv.appendChild(delDiv);

  parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
  // 存储todoList
  storage.setItem('originList', parentDiv.innerHTML);

  clearAll();
}
//初始化todoList
addNewToDo('init');
```

```css
body {
  background: #2BC0E4;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

#container {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3%;
}

#todo {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#title {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

#items-title {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

form {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.form-lines:first-child input {
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.form-lines:first-child input[type="text"] {
  width: 62%;
  height: 35px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#todoButton {
  width: 28%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

#todoButton:hover {
  background-color: #206592;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.form-lines:nth-child(2) input {
  margin: 5px auto 0;
  width: 92%;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.form-lines input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 2px solid #2980b9;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#icon {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

hr {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto 5px;
}

.todoList {
  width: 93%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin: auto auto 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.delete {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 40px 10px 0px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.content h2 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.content .date {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  margin: 0;
  width: 77%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.conten .subject {
  margin: 15px auto;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.completed {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="title">
        <div>
          <h1>
            SEF Todo List<span id="icon"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
          </h1>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="add-new-todo">
        <div id="items-title">
          <h1>Item</h1>
        </div>

        <form>
          <div class="form-lines">
            <input type="text" name="todoTitle" placeholder="Enter title" id="todoTitle">
            <input type="button" name="todoButton" value="Add" id="todoButton" onclick="addNewToDo()">
          </div>

          <div class="form-lines">
            <input type="text" name="todoContent" placeholder="Enter what To Do" id="todoContent">
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="todo"></div>
  </div>




  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>

  <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
  <script>
    (function(b, o, i, l, e, r) {
      b.GoogleAnalyticsObject = l;
      b[l] || (b[l] =
        function() {
          (b[l].q = b[l].q || []).push(arguments)
        });
      b[l].l = +new Date;
      e = o.createElement(i);
      r = o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
      e.src = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
      r.parentNode.insertBefore(e, r)
    }(window, document, 'script', 'ga'));
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: honestly I didn't try your solution because after contacting the instructor, part of the assignment is to not to store the whole <div> 
but thanks anyway, I'll update the question and add the solution I did and it would be really helpful if you check my solution and give me your feedback